# Keyboard.java blank keyboard constructor incorrect behaviour

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I tried to use this Keyboard constructor.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.html

*Keyboard(Context context, int layoutTemplateResId, CharSequence characters, int columns, int horizontalPadding)
Creates a blank keyboard from the given resource file and populates it with the specified characters in left-to-right, top-to-bottom fashion, using the specified number of columns.*

But this constructor's not work well. Searching the web, i found [this answer.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35281)
But no solution on how can i fix it.

Someone have some idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Really my suggestion would be not to use this class.  If you're doing anything non-trivial you're going to quickly grow beyond its capabilities anyway.

Comment: I need a "dynamic" keyboard that sometimes had all the alphabets, or sometimes just few letters. It appears in a dialog box, so i stand the Ok or Delete with it.